# Get hint about polyfills in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, polyfills

If we are using target: es5 and lib es2015 then the Object does not have values

```
[ts] Property ‘values’ does not exist on type ‘ObjectConstructor’. [2339]
Object.values(myObject)
```

By adding the es7 polyfill (import ‘core-js/es7/object’; in polyfills.ts) we are good to go!…

We do not get any info about the existing polyfill (obviously ) is there a way to “solve” that? Perhaps using a extension or some settings/config?

Comment: _"We do not get any info about the existing polyfill"_ what does that mean? what info are you expecting to get? What are you expecting to provide said info?

Comment: Maybe a service that would provide information about that the core-js/es7/object polyfill is needed for the current target? :)